# When using mkDerivation in Nix, is it possible to specify the shell used by `buildPhase`?

Tags: nix, nixos, flake

Suppose the following line in your `flake.nix`:

```
        foo = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
          name = "foo";
          buildPhase = ''
            #some shell script
          '';
          installPhase = ''
            #some shell script
          '';
        };
```

Is it possible to specify a shell (ideally defined with `mkShell`, or passed in as a path) to use for the `buildPhase`, `installPhase`, etc, instead of plain old `bash`?

I tried reproducing the shell environment specified elsewhere in each of the text blocks, and it feels un-Nix-y

Comment: No, I don't think so, but maybe if you asked a new question with details about your specific problem and why you think you need to do this, someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Not semantically the same, but you can run scripts written in other languages in your derivation. For example:

```hs
{
  buildPhase = ''
    ./my-build-script.py
  '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as the phases run one after the other in a single shell session. They often use and set local variables.

Any predefined phases or setup hooks provided by build inputs are designed for Bash as well.

To use another shell, you'd need to use `derivation` with a custom builder, which would mean giving up all the infrastructure `mkDerivation` provides, notably including input propagation and cross-compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's an easy way to get what I want, it turns out. I'm a little embarrassed to have asked. Solution for anyone else who might find this question. This approach allows you to reuse a shell configuration (packages, environment variables) across derivations, shells, and scripts (very handy in `flake.nix`.)

It's not quite what I was looking for, but it meets the needs that had me looking.

Do something along the lines of:

```
# ...
let
  shellHook = ''
    export SOME_VAR=1
  '';
  nativeBuildInputs = [ pkgs.foo ];

  # for `nix develop`
  my-shell = pkgs.mkShell = {
    inherit nativeBuildInputs shellHook;
    # ...
  };

  my-package = pkgs.stdenv.mkDerivation {
    inherit nativeBuildInputs shellHook;
    # ...
  };

  my-script = pkgs.writeScript ''
    #!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
    #!nix-shell -i bash -p ${builtins.concatStringsSep ' ' nativeBuildInputs}
    ${shellHook}
    # ...

  '';
  }
in {
  apps.default = {
    type = "app";
    program = "${my-script}";
  };
  packages.default = my-package;
  devShells.default = my-shell;
}
# ...
```